# Domain when simplifying division by x in intermediate step

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I got asked this question and was not exactly sure about the answer. When differentiating the function $f(x) = \cos^{-1}(\cos x^2)$ we can notice that this is equal to $x^2$ and thus differentiate to $2x$, or we can use the chain rule: $f'(x) = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-(\cos x^2)^2}}-2x\sin x^2 = 2x\frac{\sin x^2}{\sqrt{\sin^2 x^2}} = 2x$. Now I was wondering about the domain of the derivative, since if we use the chain rule to get to the answer, in the intermediate step we cannot divide by zero, so $x$ could not be equal to $0$ or $\pi$ for example. But in the final answer this should not matter right? I was wondering what is correct when a situation like this happens. When can we just blindly simplify $\frac{2x}{x}$ to $2$ without specifying the domain, and when is this not allowed?

Comment: It is $$f'(x)=-\frac{2 x \cos \left(x^2\right)}{\sqrt{1-\sin
   ^2\left(x^2\right)}}$$

Comment: $\arccos(\cos(x^2))$ is only equal to $x^2$ if $x^2$ is in the interval $[0,\pi]$, meaning, if $-\sqrt{\pi}\leq x\leq \sqrt{\pi}$. Also, the function is not differentiable when $\cos(x^2) = -1$ or $1$, so it is not differentiable at $x=\pm\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: (P.s. You should **never** simplify $\frac{2x}{x}$ to $1$. You could simplify it to $2$ if $x\neq 0$, though...)

Comment: Yes the 1 was a typo, but that was indeed what I was wondering. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good for you that you are careful. When you apply the chain rule here, you must take into account not only that the domain of $\arccos$ is $[-1,1]$ but furthermore that it is *not* differentiabl at $\pm1$. So, yes, if you differentiate $f$ using the chain rule, you get *no* conclusion about, say $f'(0)$ , since $\cos0=1$ and $\arccos$ is not differentiable at $1$.

On the other hand, you seem to think that you always have $\arccos(\cos x)=x$. Not true. This take place only when $x\in[0,\pi]$.

Comment: I was blindly following my (engineering-related math class) answer sheet, my mistake. If the question would specify that $x \in [0, \pi]$ then this simplification would be valid? And in the case it doesn't specify a domain, the domain of the original function would be restricted to $[-1, 1]$ because of arccos, and then for the derivative to $(-1, 0) \cup (0, 1)$ so that 0 is not in the domain?

Comment: If $x^2\in[0,\pi]\left(\iff x\in\left[-\sqrt\pi,\sqrt\pi\right]\right)$, then everything works just fine and the simplification will work. But if you want to apply the chain rule, then you must exclude the numbers $0$. and $\pm\sqrt\pi$. They still belong to the domain; I am just saying that you cannot simply use the chain rule in those cases anymore.